# How to read .xls/excel file in python3.3

Tags: python-3.x

I tried a couple of ways to do so but didn't found the better way to open my excel file which is as shown in below pic.

[image]

Here is one of the example I tried.

```
import xlrd 
def read_open_exls(path): 
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 
    print(book)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    read_open_exls(casemon.xls)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a workbook is printable at all.

you should first select a sheet. and then you can read values from that sheet.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
print(sheet_ranges['D18'].value)
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html